# postgresql conbine two query

Tags: postgresql

Query 1

```
SELECT cpl.product_id
FROM crm_planning_line cpl
    LEFT JOIN crm_planning cp ON cpl.crm_planning_id = cp.id 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cp.planning_date + interval '7' HOUR)=9
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cp.planning_date + interval '7' HOUR)=2022
    AND cp.salesman_id = 27
    AND cp.customer_id = 2977
```

Result 1

```
product_id | view
7359         1
8192         1
7359         1
8192         1
7357         1
```

Query 2

```
SELECT line.product_id
FROM account_invoice_line line
    LEFT JOIN account_invoice inv on inv.id=line.invoice_id
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM inv.date_invoice)=9
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM inv.date_invoice)=2022
    AND inv.user_id=27
    AND inv.partner_id=2977
```

Result 2

```
product_id | buy
7359         100
4970         200
4970         50
```

For final result, I want to combine those query where the result like this:

```
product_id | summery
7359         100,2
8192         2
7357         1
4970         250
```

Final result 2:

```
product_id | summery
    7359         100,2
    8192         0,2
    7357         0,1
    4970         250,0
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: So `SELECT a.product_id, array_agg(b.buy) AS summary FROM (… query 1 …) AS a JOIN (… query 2 …) AS b USING (product_id) GROUP BY a.product_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table_view (
    product_id int4 NULL,
    "view" int4 NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.table_buy (
    product_id int4 NULL,
    buy int4 NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_view (product_id, "view") VALUES(7359, 1);
INSERT INTO table_view (product_id, "view") VALUES(8192, 1);
INSERT INTO table_view (product_id, "view") VALUES(7359, 1);
INSERT INTO table_view (product_id, "view") VALUES(8192, 1);
INSERT INTO table_view (product_id, "view") VALUES(7357, 1);

INSERT INTO table_buy (product_id, buy) VALUES(7359, 100);
INSERT INTO table_buy (product_id, buy) VALUES(4970, 200);
INSERT INTO table_buy (product_id, buy) VALUES(4970, 50);
```

Sample Query:

```
select product_id, string_agg(t1.a1, ',')  from 
(
    select product_id, sum("buy")::text a1 from table_buy
    group by product_id
    union all 
    select product_id, sum("view")::text a1 from table_view
    group by product_id

) t1  
group by product_id
```

Comment: clear and straight answer. Thank you

Comment: You have answer it right, but I have add addition question final result 2. Thank you